# Module Not Found Error while trying to make migrations in app django "No module named 'app'"

Tags: django-models, model, crud

So I keep hitting this error when I try to make migrations after effecting changes in my models.py

```
(.venv) C:\Users\MR UWZX\Desktop\Zuri_tasks>python manage.py makemigrations     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MR UWZX\Desktop\Zuri_tasks\manage.py", line 22, in <module>    
    main()
  File "C:\Users\MR UWZX\Desktop\Zuri_tasks\manage.py", line 18, in main        
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) 
  File "C:\Users\MR UWZX\Desktop\Zuri_tasks\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\MR UWZX\Desktop\Zuri_tasks\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 420, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\MR UWZX\Desktop\Zuri_tasks\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\MR UWZX\Desktop\Zuri_tasks\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate      
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)  File "C:\Users\MR UWZX\Desktop\Zuri_tasks\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 178, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Users\MR UWZX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050,0,n _gcd_import
 in _gcd_import                                 7,
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027,File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992,  in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, ,  _call_with_frames_removed
in _find_and_load_unlocked                      0,
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import                               7,
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load                              4,
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked                      
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed                    
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in    _find_and_load_unlocked
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'musicapp'
```

I've tried deleting my database and pycache nothing works! I'd attach my models, settings and apps.py below.[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBH6x.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnuYa.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BDFt.jpg)

I've tried used Musicapp.Config as the app name but it still gives errors.

Comment: Looks like the path for the app in your INSTALLED_APPS setting should probably be `songcrud.musicapp`

Comment: @lain Shelvington This doesn't work either returns same error